# Android: Trying to expand a ScrollView to fit the white space on screen, even when I only have one line of text

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

So what I am trying to do is to be able to click on my TextView. I have a TextView inside my ScrollView and I am trying to make it so when I tap on the screen an event will happen. Currently when I tap on my TextView, the event will happen. However, the problem comes from this: when I only have one line of text, I must click on that line of text to be able to detect the onTouch. I want to expand my TextView to cover the white space on my screen(I have two buttons on the bottom of my screen). The problem with using real gesture control is that it detects also when I click on my buttons on the screen so that makes it useless for single tap. I've been trying to figure this out but for some reason it does not work. Here is my code.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.close:
                finish();
                break;  
            case R.id.flashcard:
                if(tv.getText().equals(myCursor.getString(iFront)))      {
                    tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iBack));
                    break;
                }
                tv.setText(myCursor.getString(iFront));
                break;
            case R.id.add_new:
                Intent list = new Intent("com.example.flashcards.ADD_FLASHCARD");
                startActivity(list);
                break;
        }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flashcard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_new"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:text="Add New" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:text="close" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to set [`fillViewport`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3afillViewport) to `true` for your `ScrollView`. Romain Guy has a more in depth explanation [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/).

Comment: Gosh! you just saved me about 3 hours of trying... I've been trying to  figure it out and you just made my day! :) Thanks.